# Static properties on base class and inheritance

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

I recently ran into an issue with static variables/methods when dealing with inheritance. The code reads something like this:

```
<?php
Class TestBase
{
    public static $values;

    public static function addValue($value)
    {
        static::$values[] = $value;
    }
}

Class TestOne extends TestBase
{

}
Class TestTwo extends TestBase
{

}

TestOne::addvalue('one');
TestOne::addvalue('two');
TestOne::addvalue('three');
var_dump(TestOne::$values);
echo "<br /><br />";

TestTwo::addvalue('four');
TestTwo::addvalue('five');
TestTwo::addvalue('six');
var_dump(TestTwo::$values);
echo "<br /><br />";

var_dump(TestOne::$values);
?>
```

This produces the output:

> array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=> string(3) "two" [2]=> string(5)
>   "three" }
>
> array(6) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=> string(3) "two"
>   [2]=> string(5) "three" [3]=> string(4) "four" [4]=> string(4) "five"
>   [5]=> string(3) "six" }
>
> array(6) { [0]=> string(3) "one" [1]=>
>   string(3) "two" [2]=> string(5) "three" [3]=> string(4) "four" [4]=>
>   string(4) "five" [5]=> string(3) "six" }

As you can see, any values added to either are added to both. It was my understanding that the static:: keyword in methods binds to the inherited class, not the parent class so I am thinking this stems from the fact that only one static::$values will ever be created and both assume I am referencing that value. This can be fixed by re-declaring public static $values on each of the classes which extends from the base, but is there a simpler way to do this such that each gets their own static copy? Any keywords or tricks that will prevent the need to re-declare on each inherited class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am thinking this stems from the fact that only one static::$values will ever be created and both assume I am referencing that value.

Correct.

> This can be fixed by re-declaring public static $values on each of the classes which extends from the base, but is there a simpler way to do this such that each gets their own static copy? Any keywords or tricks that will prevent the need to re-declare on each inherited class?

No, there isn't anything like that. However, what does the trick is to avoid static stuff as much as possible. When you run into a situation like this one, that's most of the time a good indicator that your code design needs some optimization.